# error LNK2019 e LNK1120 (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

**project:** *03 - Criacao de funcoes e estruturas de decisao*
**file:** *Criacao de funcoes e estruturas de decisao.cpp*

```
include <iostream>
include <stdlib.h>
include <stdio.h>  

using namespace std;  

int soma(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;  
}

void mensagem() {
    printf ("Hello World!");
    printf ("soma: %d", soma(10,20));
}
```

Errors:

> Error 1   03 - Criacao de funcoes e estruturas de decisao error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   MSVCRTD.lib
>   Error 2   03 - Criacao de funcoes e estruturas de decisao fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\geovani.moura\Desktop\c++\Debug\03 - Criacao de funcoes e estruturas de decisao.exe

because giving this error?

Comment: You're missing `main()`.

Comment: Where's `main` function?

Answer (score 0):

In general, every <kbd>C</kbd> program must define `main()` exactly once with external linkage.

You're missing `main()`.

If your intended entry point is `void mensagem()`, you should call this from within `main()`.
[Although there are ways to define another entry point, they are non-standard and/or non-portable -- just stick with `main()`]

A simple example would be:

```
int main()
{
    mensagem();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

or

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    mensagem();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**NOTE:** in the context of this code, `main()` should be listed following the two functions you've created. To change the order of functions, one possibility would be to declare prototypes ahead of all your functions. Also, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined in `stdlib.h`, which was included by your code.

Without `stdlib.h` and `EXIT_SUCCESS`:

```
int main()
{
    mensagem();
    return 0;
}
```

**SIDE NOTE:** You're mixing <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>C++</kbd> headers. `<stdio.h>` is what you want for `printf()`. Additionally, you may find the output is not formatting as you intended. You can use the `'\n'` (newline) character to output new lines.